# Accessing realm and filter results in different threads

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, realm

**Hello everyone**!

I've run into a big problem. I'm trying to access the realm data in main thread but also since I need to do a lot of synchronizing operations with the data such as update, insert etc I decided to search if there is a possibility to do all of these operations asynchronously but I'm getting different errors for every method that I'm trying to implement.

I'm creating the realm database as follows:

```
realm = try Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(
                  fileURL: fileURL,
                  encryptionKey: nil,
                  schemaVersion: schemaVersion,
                  objectTypes: objectTypes))
```

Accessing data as follows:

```
guard let realm = realm else {
  return nil
}
let results = realm.objects(SPUserModel.self)
return Array(results)
```

Doing all of these upsert operations in the mainthread will raise my memory up to 1GB which is bad. Making them asynchronously may be a solution but there are different threads and that's an issue.

Would be glad if you can help me with this.

Comment: There may be another issue here; Returning results as an array `return Array(results)` disconnects those objects from Realm and they will no longer live update; they will not be updated when observed and events will not fire for them; an Array is not the same as a Results object. Additionally as you have discovered, Realm results are lazily loaded and do not occupy memory until they are needed - however, casting those to an array takes up memory for every object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension Realm {
class func realmInstance() -> Realm? {
   let realm = try Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(
                  fileURL: fileURL,
                  encryptionKey: nil,
                  schemaVersion: schemaVersion,
                  objectTypes: objectTypes))
   return realm
}
```

access :

```
DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
    Realm.realmInstance()?.objects(SPUserModel.self)
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what this does? This line `Realm.realmInstance()?.objects(SPUserModel.self)` in particular?

Comment: I think returns all the objects of that type from the database

Comment: @MihailStoica Hmm, it doesn't appear to do that. If you want to return all objects in your database, you would need somewhere to put them, like a results var e.g. `let myResultsObject = realm.objects(SPUserModel.self)`and it doesn't do that. Also, that extension configures realm every time `Realm.realmInstance` is called and that's not needed as once a Realm is configured, it keeps that configuration until changed. It's also reconfiguring realm on a background thread which is again, not needed. The issue is the OP is casting Realm results to an array which is gobbling up the memory.